# Fade and slide animation for JavaFX ListView

Tags: java, listview, animation, javafx, transition

I am implementing a search bar with an impromptu list result with JavaFX, I intend to use the ListView by clearing and loading a new list of items every query, but I also wanted ListView to animate the list cells to fade in and slide up to there respected positions in the list. I am thinking of using Path and fade transition, however I don't know where to implement this without affecting listview's function. How do i animate this?

Comment: The "fade" should be easy enough, just keep track of which cells are not empty and apply the fade transition(s) to them. "Sliding" on the other hand is going to be either extremely difficult or impossible. The problem is that it's completely at odds with how the list view works: if you remove, for example, the first item in the list view, then the cell that was used to represent it is typically not removed, but it is reused to display the item that was previously below it, and so on down the list. (This implementation is not guaranteed, by design.)

Comment: i see, here i go implementing again.